# Why does LINQ take more time to execute than foreach?

Tags: c#, linq

I ran the following code first:

```
var stringList = new[]{"A","BB","CCC","DDDD"};
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
foreach (var s in stringList)
{
    dictionary.Add(s.Length,s);
}
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
Console.ReadKey();
```

execution time was : 00:00:00.0000205

then I ran the following code...

```
var stringList = new[]{"A","BB","CCC","DDDD"};
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
var dictionary = stringList.ToDictionary(s => s.Length);
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
Console.ReadKey();
```

execution time was : 00:00:00.0037431

Does this prove that foreach is better than LINQ??

Comment: No it proves writing performance tests is not easy task as shown in your case.

Comment: @Atish, run this test 100000 times and do average.
and than run this rest on a string list with 100000 random strings a few dozen times and publish the results

Comment: If you are going to perform micro-benchmarks you really should use a larger dataset to offset warm up costs.

Comment: Use a profiler like DotTrace to compare call stacks.

Comment: Premature optimisation, you say?

Comment: It may be premature optimization but I just wanted to know as I am a beginner. So your comment is not very much intelligent @DavidOsborne, you say?

Comment: @NahumLitvin, I run this test over 154015 rows in my data base and saw that foreach takes more time.
var db = new InceptaDbContext();
            var chmistList = new List<CH_INFO>();
            Console.WriteLine(db.CH_INFO.Count());
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            chmistList = db.CH_INFO.ToList();

            //foreach (var chInfo in db.CH_INFO)
            //{
            //    chmistList.Add(chInfo);
            //}

            stopWatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your example:

- Tiny sample size. Four elements in the array?? Try 1,000,000
- In the first example the dictionary object is created **outside** of the stopwatch. Object creation is a factor in speed, particularly with such a tiny example
- The LINQ code uses a delegate. Admittedly this is a common usage in LINQ but to get a true comparison either both should use methods or both should use delegates.

You should check out Jon Skeet's [blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/02/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-todictionary/) on this subject

Answer (score 2):

> Does it prove that foreach is better than LINQ??

No, it proves that it is faster.

Better is a subjective notion. For example if you prefer to have more readable and compact code and performance is not your utmost priority for the project and have determined that this is not a bottleneck, LINQ might actually be better.

Comment: You already saw it. It's a minor difference that you probably shouldn't be concerned about unless you are doing some micro-optimizations.

Comment: No, it only proves that it is faster _in this particular case_.

Comment: @Rik, that's not true. Look at how the .ToDictionary extension method is implemented. It contains far more IL code than a single `foreach` loop. It has error checking, ... So it is not in this particular case. It is in ALL cases. But I repeat once again: the difference might be so negligible that you probably shouldn't be concerned about unless you are doing some extreme micro-optimizations of your code that you probably shouldn't be doing anyways.

Comment: I'm sure the `foreach` is, in fact, faster, but OP's test didn't prove anything; inspecting the IL code did.

Answer (score 2):

You can see how `ToDictionary` really looks using .NET sources or ILSpy:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (keySelector == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("keySelector");
    }
    if (elementSelector == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("elementSelector");
    }

    Dictionary<TKey, TElement> dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TElement>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource current in source)
    {
        dictionary.Add(keySelector(current), elementSelector(current));
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

As you can see, it uses `foreach` too! However, the parameter checks and `Func` delegates makes that a little bit less efficient then your custom code, with just `Dictionary.Add` method call. However, I think in real application the *penalty* of using `ToDictionary` instead of custom `foreach` doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Why?

Because there is no magic, LINQ version does much processing than the non-LINQ version.

I've wrote a small piece of code that shows what LINQ does internally. You can see almost identical performances. Also do note I've added the instantiation of the dictionary inside the loop:

```
int testCount = 1000000;
var stringList = new[] { "A", "BB", "CCC", "DDDD" };

Func<string, string> elementSelector = (value) => value;

var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    Func<string, int> keySelector = (value) => value.Length;
    foreach (var s in stringList)
    {
        if (keySelector != null && elementSelector != null)
        {
            dictionary.Add(keySelector(s), elementSelector(s));
        }
    }
}

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / testCount);

var stopwatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
{
    var dictionary2 = stringList.ToDictionary(s => s.Length);
}

stopwatch2.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / testCount);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: In your example linq also take more time

Comment: @AtishDipongkor Of course, because there are some extra-processing I did not wrote. Basically, it checks that all parameters of the extension method are valid (test for null equality). The non-LINQ version I wrote provides *similar* results